# Get Parents Node From XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

i have a XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<childrens>
 <child id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
  <child id="2" value="Apparel" parent_id="1">
    <child id="3" value="Accessories" parent_id="2">
        <child id="4" value="Handbags" parent_id="3">
            <child id="5" value="Jewelry" parent_id="4"/>
        </child>
    </child>
  </child>
 </child>
</childrens>
```

i want to find parents upto particular element

i have written this code

which returns me all the parents

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('child[value="test"]').parents().each(function(){
            var i = $(this).attr('value');
            alert(i);
        });
    }
});
});
```

i want parents up to where `id=2` and `value=Apparel`

if i use `.parents('[value="Apparel"]')` then it will returns only one name that is `Apparel`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) for this:

```
$(xml).find('child[value="test"]').parentsUntil('[value="Apparel"]').each( ...
```

From the docs:

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, up to but not including the element matched by the selector,
>   DOM node, or jQuery object.